# how to show details of PieChart sector on click?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, charts, pie-chart

I have created A pie Chart in Prime faces with values from the database. I want to Make the Pie Chart Interactive such that When you click on the Sector, the Label represented in the sector Should Show .
this is my xhtml:

```
 <p:pieChart id="pie" dataFormat="value"
                    value="#{StatsImpl.getStats2(ProjetComponent.projet.idprojet)}"
                    legendPosition="w" title="Tache Critique et Non Critique"
                    style="width:400px;height:300px" />
```

this is my create pie Chart model method:

```
public PieChartModel getStats2(Integer idprojet)
    {
        List<Tache> listTaches=tacheService.getTacheProjet(idprojet);
        int critique=0;
        int nomCritique=0;
        for(int i=0;i<listTaches.size();i++)

        {
            if(listTaches.get(i).getType()!=null){
            if(listTaches.get(i).getType().equals("Critique"))critique++;
            else nomCritique++;
        }
        }
        pieChart.set("Tache Critique", critique);
        pieChart.set("Tache Non Critique", nomCritique);
        return pieChart;
    }
```

this is a screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Do you want to show label as a tooltip on clicking the sector?

Comment: try to use `<p:ajax event="itemSelect">` as the show case demonstrated: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/interactive.xhtml